# How to store ASCII table in c++

Tags: c++, compression, hashtable

I have troubles with storing ASCII table I don't want to write them by my hand all 255 of them, I need to store them in a hash table in order to compress a string file with respect to Ziv-Lempel algorithm. So do you have any suggestions so is tthere another way to store them in a hash table ?

Thank you.

EDITED:

```
HashTable::HashTable(){

char charToBeStored;
theList.resize(4096);
for(int i= 0; i<256; i++){
    charToBeStored = i;
    string stringToBeStored = charToBeStored; //Problem is here I also need to store
// strings beside char. I need to store them both 
    theList.push_back(charToBeStored); // Used <vectors> -> vector<string> theList;
  }
}
```

Solved(Thanks for your replies I figured that this was a very basic question sorry for that.)

```
HashTable::HashTable(){
    unsigned char charToBeStored;
    theList.resize(4096);

    for(int i= 0; i<256; i++){
        charToBeStored = i;
        string stringToBeStored = "";
        stringToBeStored += charToBeStored;
        theList.push_back(stringToBeStored);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. If you `static_cast` a `char` to `int` it will give you the character's ASCII value: `static_cast<int>('a')` gives 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII is just 0 to 255, so write a for loop that stores unsigned chars into the hash table from 0 to 255.

Comment: After you mentioned I did that but now I have to store also strings in this list (I used vectors).

Answer (score 0):

To generate all ascii characters:

```
char[256] asciichars;
for(int i = 0;i<256;++i)
{
    char[i] = static_cast<char>(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added my code to the question.